# How do I create an SAP interface to pull some data from our webapplication?

Tags: java, soa, saprfc, webdynpro

We have a Java web application built on a relational database and we would like to create a SAP module to pull some data in from this application into SAP.

What would be involved?

My understanding so far is that we would need a Java Web Dynpro interface built to import the data from our web-app using SOA.

Also, looking for a vendor who would be able to implement this module for us. I have already looked at some big-name Indian vendors but I feel our requirements would be sufficiently small and un-complicated to not required expensive big-name outsourcing firms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need webdynpro to perform this operation. Webdynpro can be seen as a framework, and it won't be easy to integrate it into your own application.

[JCO](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6f/1bd5c6a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm) is a java component (library) allowing the connection to a SAP system. It's quite easy to use. I've integrated the lib into application on WebSphere and Tomcat, without any problem. Some tutorials are available [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/SAPJCo/article.html)

The JCO will be used to call Remote-enabled functions on the SAP side (RFC). There are a lot of standard function available. Since you didn't gave us any information on your field, i can't really help on this. If you got access to an R/3 system, transaction BAPI can give you an idea of what already exists.

If there is no function that correspond to your needs, then an ABBAPer can help you. If you don't need a "expensive big-name outsourcing firms", then a freelance could be the solution.

However, if you plug into an existing SAP component (and i don't see why you would want to connect to SAP if it does not use SAP...), the apparently "simple" request can be more complex than you think.

Regards
Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

You can pull data from your app. in many ways.
If your app. has some web service interface you can build web service clients in SAP to fetch the data you need. See [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw2004s/helpdata/en/bf/d005244e9d1d4d92b2fe7935556b4c/content.htm).
Using Native SQL you can access directly from SAP to your app. database, suppossing you have network acces to it. See [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/fc/eb3976358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).
Also, as stated in the previous answer, you can acces SAP system from your java app. through [JCo](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6f/1bd5c6a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm) or through [web services](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw2004s/helpdata/en/e5/a68d10f4eb894087fc9c1c3f9ae433/content.htm).
There are more imaginative forms, as plain text file transfer, [EDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Data_Interchange), [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer), [SAP PI](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/14/80243b4a66ae0ce10000000a11402f/frameset.htm)... SAP is full of ways to interface with the rest of the world!

Regards